# Deploy Retail Windows Images on WDS?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-server-2008-r2

I have 10 laptops I would like to upgrade from Windows Vista to Windows 10. They're not old but for some reason my friend installed Windows Vista on them... Anyway, my home server is running Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard (had a license laying around at work). I decided to download Windows 10 Pro with that media creation tool from Microsoft and to speed up the process I decided I would just use WDS to deploy it on those 10 laptops.

While playing with it for a while I came to the conclusion that those are retail images, so I can't even add them to WDS. Is there any way I could deploy a retail image with WDS? I really don't want to have to burn a DVD and have to wait for the computers to install Windows one by one.

Answer (score 1):

The main Windows image in retail versions is now usually an ESD, not a WIM. Windows Deployment Services does not know how to handle ESDs, so you'll need to convert it to a WIM. First, copy out `install.esd` from the `sources` folder.

Run this command to get a list of images inside the ESD:

```
dism /get-wiminfo /wimfile:install.esd
```

That gives you the different OS editions inside the ESD and their respective indexes. Now run this command to pull out the one you want into a WIM file ([source](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/125905-change-esd-to-wim)):

```
dism /export-image /sourceimagefile:install.esd /sourceindex:1 /destinationimagefile:install.wim /compress:max /checkintegrity
```

Change `/sourceindex:1` to use the index you prefer. Once the command finishes, you'll have an `install.wim` that WDS will accept as an install image.

Note that you'll need to run these commands on a Windows 10 computer; the Windows 7 (Windows Server 2008 R2) version of DISM doesn't seem to know the `/export-image` switch.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know WDS well enough to answer this part of your question but I tried to create custom win10 images using *Windows Imaging and Configuration Designer* based on the retail images and it wouldn't work (even though I couldn't find **any** reference as to why that is).

What I did in the end is use the sysprep process:

- Install Windows on one machine
- Install any applications  you will need on all laptops
- Run Sysprep and reboot into [Windows PE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825109.aspx)
- From WinPE, [copy the image using DISM](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825072.aspx) to a second USB stick or to a network share
- Boot every other laptop with the WinPE and copy the image to it.

It's certainly less comfortable than WDS but it still beats running a full install on all machines.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you’re encountering is likely that you’re using media created by the Media Creation Tool, in which case the ISO you generated contains an ESD (encrypted installation file) rather than a WIM (unencrypted image). Since WDS looks for a WIM file, the Media Creation Tool ISO fails.

I can’t go into details, but there are tools that will convert the ESD into a WIM.

Many ways to acquire Windows 10 do not have this issue, for example MSDN and Volume License media contain WIM files, not ESD.